# Scripts loaded in default template not working in views in laravel 5

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel-5

Why is my js not working as it should in edit.blade.php view. My views are structured as follows:

Filename: profile_main.blade.php

```
 @extends('layouts.main')

    @section('head')

    @yield('style') 

    @stop

    <!-- Available at the footer of page before body tag closes --> 

@section('scripts')
        <script src="{{ URL::asset('js/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ URL::asset('js/search.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ URL::asset('js/application.js') }}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' : $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content') }
            });
        </script>
    @stop
```

Filename: training_main.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.profile_main')

@section('style')
    <link href="{{ URL::asset('css/application/index.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
@stop

@section('body')
    <div id="content-header">
        <img alt="user_icon" src="{{ asset('images/general/admission_page_logo.jpg') }}" class="img-responsive"/>
        <h1>@yield('page_heading')</h1>
        <h3>@yield('page_desc')</h3>
    </div>
    <hr class="header_underline"/>
    @yield('training_body')
@stop
```

Filename: edit.blade.php

```
@extends('trainings.training_main')

@section('page_heading')
    Edit Training Details
@stop
@section('page_desc')
    General
@stop

@section('training_body')

@stop
```

I have some jquery functions in application.js. I notice that these functions are not working in edit.blade.php. For example

Filename: application.js

```
$("document").ready(function() { alert('Great') });
```

It does not alert when the edit.blade.php view is loaded. But when I look at the page source, everything seems to be loaded fine like so:

```
<!-- Javascript -->
    <script src="http://localhost:8000/js/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:8000/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:8000/js/main.js"></script>
        <script src="http://localhost:8000/js/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:8000/js/search.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:8000/js/application.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' : $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content') }
        });
    </script>
    </body>
```

What could be the problem here? What are my missing?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with my js. My js look like so:

```
$("document").ready(function() {

    limitCharacters();
    $("#edit_academic_form").on('submit', updateAcademic);
    $("#edit_training_form").on('submit', updateTraining);
}
```

The function limitCharacters() had some syntax errors thus preventing the codes beneath it from ever getting called. I resolved issues with the function and now everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

check with `php artisan route:list` on your terminal,
in 'edit' URI, will showed :

```
home/{home}/edit
```

its reason why your js not run, to solve the problem you can rewrite js path in your edit.blade.php.

Or if you have other solution please tell me. Thanks